# How to add cq:listener to a component

Tags: osgi, aem

I am trying to add `cq:listener` https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/developing/components/edit_config.html#cq:listeners to my component so that after selecting an asset and clicking "ok", the page refreshes.

This is how the component looks on the screen where I select an asset and click ok.

[image]

In my code, the `dialog.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="tabpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <tab1
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
                title="Tab">
                    <items
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                            <asset-reference
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                fieldLabel="Foo Bar:"
                                fieldDescription="Select the asset under /content/dam/foo-sync"
                                name="./fileReference"
                                xtype="pathfield"
                                rootPath="/content/dam/evernote-sync"/>
                    </items>
            </tab1>
        </items>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

`_cq_editConfig.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig">
    <cq:dropTargets jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <fileReference
            jcr:primaryType="cq:DropTargetConfig"
            accept="[text/.*]"
            groups="[media]"
            propertyName="./fileReference"/>
    </cq:dropTargets>
</jcr:root>
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a node with name `cq:listeners` and type as `cq:EditListenersConfig` as a child of the `cq:EditConfig` node. Add the property `afteredit` to the newly created node with value `REFRESH_PAGE`, to refresh the page once the component is edited. By default this value is `REFRESH_SELF`, hence only the component is refreshed after edit and not the entire page.

The `_cq_editConfig.xml` would look something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig">
    <cq:listeners jcr:primaryType="cq:EditListenersConfig"
        afteredit="REFRESH_PAGE"/>
    <cq:dropTargets jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <fileReference
            jcr:primaryType="cq:DropTargetConfig"
            accept="[text/.*]"
            groups="[media]"
            propertyName="./fileReference"/>
    </cq:dropTargets>
</jcr:root>
```

More details can be found in the [link mentioned in the question](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/developing/components/edit_config.html#cq:listeners) itself.

Answer (score 2):

You might try the following in your _cq_editConfig.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0" jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig">
 <cq:listeners
     jcr:primaryType="cq:EditListenersConfig"
     afterdelete="REFRESH_PAGE"
     afteredit="REFRESH_PAGE"
     afterinsert="REFRESH_PAGE"
     afterMove="REFRESH_PAGE"/>
</jcr:root>
```